# Convert c# by-reference type to the matching non-by-reference type

Tags: c#, reflection

I examine the parameters of a C# method using reflection. The method has some out parameters and for these I get back types, which have IsByRef=true. For example if the parameter is declared as "out string xxx", the parameter has type System.String&. Is there a way to convert System.String& back to System.String? The solution should of course not only work for System.String but for any type.

Comment: Mind if I change the title from "reference" to "by-reference"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`Type.GetElementType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx).

Demo:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Test
{
    public void Foo(ref string x)
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Foo");
        Type stringByRef = method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
        Console.WriteLine(stringByRef);
        Type normalString = stringByRef.GetElementType();
        Console.WriteLine(normalString);        
    }
}
```