# C# getting the base type of a reference type

Tags: c#, reflection, types, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert c# by-reference type to the matching non-by-reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454363/convert-c-sharp-by-reference-type-to-the-matching-non-by-reference-type)

While writing some code involving heavy use of reflection, I came across the problem that I don't know how to identify the types of "byref" parameters. Let me illustrate with a bit of sample code:

```
class ReflectionTest {
    public void Test()
        MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod("SomeMethod");

        ParameterInfo pi = mi.GetParameters()[0];
        // prints "System.Object"
        Console.WriteLine(pi.ParameterType.ToString());
        // prints "True"
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(Object).Equals(pi.ParameterType));

        ParameterInfo piRef = mi.GetParameters()[1];
        // prints "System.Object&"
        Console.WriteLine(piRef.ParameterType.ToString());
        // prints "False"
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(Object).Equals(piRef.ParameterType));
    }

    public void SomeMethod(object obj, ref object objRef) {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

So the type of the `ref` parameter apparently is something entirely different from `System.Object`. Well, fair enough, but I don't see any way to deduce that `SomeType&` is a reference to an object of type `SomeType` - short of taking the `ToString()` representation, chopping off the "&" at the end and try looking up the resulting name. There has to be a more systematic way to do that, surely?

Or even if that is not possible, and I have to do it the other way around: what would I have to do to get a `Type` object representing `SomeType&` (instead of plain `SomeType`) so I could test for equality to that?

Comment: See also (other way round): [`Type.MakeByRefType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makebyreftype.aspx)